# Dynamically switching query in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am working on spark-streaming.

If I want to change my input query for each 10 times of query execution, or I want to switch my query for every 10 minutes, is that possible or not? As what I know once I create my streaming context, I could not change its logic of calculation. I am wondering, is there any possibility to switch my SQL query dynamically or not?
Thanks for your kindness help.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to do? Currently, the question has one close vote and might get closed in the future. Also, it will greatly improve the chance of getting answers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added the example below.